# How to retain the imageview size based on image size in ios?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Hi in my IPad application i have a list of Image Views and data means image for those imageviews i am getting from the server. I am able to load all images in respected imageviews without any issue. But here i observed one obnormality that is few images are looking good in resolution in imageviews and few images are looking stretched in imageviews. As per my knowledge i feel this is happen because the image size is more than that imageview size so it's happen. But that data i am getting from the server so i cannot control the size. So anyone can show any solution how to fix this issue. Means i don't want to stretch the images in imageviews. please help me.

Comment: yourImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; try this and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this i hope this will help

```
yourImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 1):

As spynet mentioned, Try UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

or add this method to resize image to the size you want

```
- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)imagerotate  { 

        CGImageRef imgRef = imagerotate.CGImage;

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    CGFloat boundHeight;

    boundHeight = bounds.size.height;  
    bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width; 
    bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
    transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0); //use angle/360 *MPI

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);   
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform); 
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageCopy, nil, nil, nil);
return imageCopy;   

}
```

and add this to call the method

```
UIImage *imgResized=[self scaleAndRotateImage:imageReceived];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot scarletWitch.